# Filter table records based on others tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table "all_data" which consists 2 set of records

```
a) Independent records which should get fetched all times 
b) All records from table "all_product"
```

Now I am also having few more tables like 
    'MS_product', 'apple_product' ,'Linux_product' and all these tables are subset of table 'all_product'.

I already have used left or right join but looks like this will not be usefful.

I want to fetch all the Independent records from table 'all_data' and only matched records from other tables i.e. 'ms_product' so final output should have 
    all independent records + matched record from 'MS_product' or 'apple_product' or 'Linux_product' table.

Comment: What is the reason for the "all_data table" approach?

Comment: @B001ᛦ the same reason for `all_product` containing the datas of 3 others tables. This is to make sure that the duplicated datas will become corrupted over time and the tables impossible to maintain. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Because 'all_data' table we generating using cron job to save the screen loading time and its default view for screen. If some user wants to apply filter then we others tables will come into play.

Comment: Creepy approach :/ @Cid

Comment: @B001ᛦ that was sarcastic

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MINUS operator for the first query :

```
SELECT *
FROM all_records

MINUS

(
    SELECT *
    FROM MS_product

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM Apple_product
)
```

It will gives you all the tuples who are not in the MS_product and Apple_product tables.

However I don't recommend to design your database like you are doing. Prefer a single table with a dedicated column for the brand product.

Comment: EXCEPT for Postgre and SQL Server, MINUS for MySQL and Oracle